# We are unable to download iOS enterprise apps after upgrading devices to iOS 14

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, enterprise, ios14

We distribute enterprise apps via our own web site.  Starting with iOS 14, we are unable to download apps.  The error message is "Unable to install *appname*.  Please try again later."

Answer (score 0):

The error was resolved by updating the server's TLS to v1.2.

Answer (score 0):

Check your app.plist and make sure you use **https** in *software-package* url setting.
Same thing for install url (itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=**https**:\...)

This should resolve the issue